# PHP convert CSV to JSON multi level

Tags: php, json, csv, data-conversion, csvtojson

I have a CSV data looks like this :
ps.csv

```csv
id|firstName|lastName|address|extId|extName
001|Kapil|Parames|address01|AA01|AA
002|David|Vuitton|address01|AA02|AA
002|David|Vuitton|address02|BB02|BB
003|Jean|Paul|address01|AA03|AA
```

And i need an output JSON to look like this :

```json
[
    {
        "id": "001",
        "firstName": "Kapil",
        "lastName": "Parames",
        "address": [{
            "address": "address01"
        }],
        "ext": [{
            "extId": "AA01",
            "extName": "AA"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Vuitton",
        "address": [{
                "address": "address01"
            },
            {
                "address": "address02"
            }
        ],
        "ext": [{
                "extId": "AA02",
                "extName": "AA"
            },
            {
                "extId": "BB02",
                "extName": "BB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "003",
        "firstName": "Jean",
        "lastName": "Paul",
        "address": [{
            "address": "address01"
        }],
        "ext": [{
            "extId": "AA03",
            "extName": "AA"
        }]
    }
]
```

I can convert it to JSON. But the problem is i would like to add "address" and "extId", "extName" into multi level array if the person already exists in the list.

Comment: Then build a lookup for that, while you iterate over the CSV records.

Answer (score 0):

So following PHP code is working for me :

```php
$csv = file('ps.csv');
$csvArray = [];

foreach ($csv as $line) {
    $csvArray[] = str_getcsv($line, '|', ',');
}

$jsonArray = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < count($csvArray); $i++) {

    $found = -1;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($jsonArray); $j++) {
        if (in_array($csvArray[$i][0], $jsonArray[$j])) {
            $found = $j;
        }
    }

    if ($found < 0) {
        $jsonArray[] = array(
            'id' => $csvArray[$i][0],
            'firstName' => $csvArray[$i][1],
            'lastName' => $csvArray[$i][2],
            'address' => array(
                [
                    'address' => $csvArray[$i][3]
                ]
            ),
            'ext' => array(
                [
                    'extId' => $csvArray[$i][4],
                    'extName' => $csvArray[$i][5]
                ]
            )
        );
    } else {
        $addressArray = array(
            'address' => $csvArray[$i][3]
        );

        $extArray = array(
            'extId' => $csvArray[$i][4],
            'extName' => $csvArray[$i][5]
        );

        array_push($jsonArray[$found]['address'], $addressArray);
        array_push($jsonArray[$found]['ext'], $extArray);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
```

Is that correct or is there any other way to do ?